# How to acess backend of vaadin server application via HTTP Api (REST)?

Tags: java, rest, vaadin7

I have a **VAADIN framework application** which runs on a **Tomcat server**. It does some calculations and displays the results. However, I also want to **access** the computed results in the **backend** through an API (I thought about REST, I got inspired by this [vaadin blog post](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/making-rest-apis-for-vaadin-applications) ) from another server.

I already thought about doing **RPC calls**, but that would create unnecessary dependencies and I don't want to include the whole app.

So I am searching for an idea/solution to implement an API interface which allows to access the backend data/calculations from another server (Yes, I know that I have to use CORS).

How would I best do this?

Comment: That kind of depends on multiple factors, such as project constraints (eg: can you refactor and extract a stand alone module which can be called both from your vaadin application and some other 3rd party app via REST), how long is the data available in-memory for access (eg: is it only available during the calculation? if yes, then what's the point of exposing it via a new REST method?)?, etc. To me it sounds like you need a stand-alone module accessible via REST but I feel that as the question stands now, it's not very clear what you want and the answers will mainly be opinion-based...

Comment: I thought about this a bit and came to the conclusion that your idea in splitting up the backend as standalone app would be the best. Then I can it access the same way in both cases